# Iterate over a dictionay inside a list

Tags: python

1. The below is a list of lists which has a dictionary

   ```
   (Pdb) [group.orgs for group in membership.group_permission_roles]

   [[{'moid': '5d2d5ee66972652d30d5e456', 'object_name': None}], [{'moid': '5d3127ec6972652d30d60fdd', 'object_name': None}], [{'moid': '5d2f2e2b6972652d30d606f4', 'object_name': None}]]
   ```
2. How can we fetch the values of each 'moid' in a list.
3. When i try to iterate as below, the values are getting overwritten

   ```
   (Pdb) [org.moid for org in group.orgs for group in membership.group_permission_roles ]

   ['5d2f2e2b6972652d30d606f4', '5d2f2e2b6972652d30d606f4', '5d2f2e2b6972652d30d606f4']
   ```

Comment: You have done it exactly correct. What values are overwritten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second piece of code only works because you have previously defined `group`, in the first code (and are using Python 2 where list comprehension variables leak out into the surrounding scope). The `group` is not from the current iteration at all, but always refers to the final iteration of the original list comprehension.

Nested list comprehensions are "backwards", because they follow the same structure as a standard nested for loop. In your case, the loop would look like this:

```
for group in membership.group_permission_roles:
  for org in group.orgs:
    ... org.moid  ...
```

so the nested list comprehension should be:

```
[org.moid for group in membership.group_permission_roles for org in group.orgs]
```